# Why new column get emptied when next task starts?

Tags: informatica-powercenter

I have 3 tasks in a Workflow :

- task 1 : cleans a table
- task 2 : loads a flat file into that table
- task 3 : logs operation as completed

I have added a *new column to task 2*, and, as I look in the database while this task runs, I see the new column be populated.

The problem resides **when task 3 runs, it clears my new columns**, leaving it empty.
What is going on? And how to fix it?

My colleagues proposed to me to recreate the task 3, which I did and it worked fine for some workflow. But for another workflow, this "dirty" fix does not work anymore.

There is no logic in task 3 that is supposed to do this kind of "cleanup".

What am I missing about Informatica internals?

*Also, to mention that if I disable task 3, the columns stays populated with the good values.*

EDIT : ( after being asked more details ) the tasks are of type Session. Task 2 just moves data from flat file to table (it also calls some PLSQL package to calculate some fields, and then fills them in the end table target). Task 3 moves data from a header to a log table, calls some PLSQL package to do similar things to task 2, plus calls some PLSQL afterwards (this last step does not touch the data itself from task 2, the thing that gets weirdly cleaned)

Comment: Need some more detail on what is inside your task 3? Is it a session or command task? Are you running any script inside it?

Comment: @Samik updated the Q with some extra details

Comment: There have to be some logic in your task 3 that is overwriting the data loaded in task 2. Check the target instance in the mapping for task 3, if it has the new columns.

Answer (score 0):

the issue is totally not related to informatica from what I discovered. indeed there was something in the task 3' sql package